# My app crashes when I call a module who's function is to switch to an activity which is inside the module

Tags: java, android

I am creating a module that switches activity from the current one in a user's project to a specific activity inside the module.

Inside the module is a class that acts as a bridge between the project that wants to use the library and the activity it should switch to. The bridge class in the module looks like this:

```
 public class Starter extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;

    public Starter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void OpenOkraWidget(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, OkraWebActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

> the OkraWebActivity.class being called in the intent above is a class
>   inside the module with its layout also.

while in my main project class I call the module like this:

```
    public class ProjectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_project);

        button = findViewById(R.id.okra_btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openOkraWidget();
            }
        });

    }

    public void openOkraWidget(){
        Starter starter = new Starter(ProjectActivity.this);
        starter.OpenOkraWidget();
    }
}
```

My problem is when I try to run the code I get

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
>   android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object
>   reference
>
> which comes from the Intent intent = new Intent(this.context,
>   OkraWebActivity.class);
>   startActivity(intent); in the Starter.class inside the module.

Why do I get this error, why doesn't my code work properly as expected?

Comment: You never create an Object of `Activity` in android .. `new Starter()` this is the culprit .. Please read about `Activity` component a little more ..

Comment: @ADM so how do I bridge the gap that would enable me to switch activities

Comment: For now just copy the code of method `OpenOkraWidget` inside `ProjectActivity` from `Starter`..

Answer (score 0):

Starter shouldn't be an activity.  The startActivity method it inherits from Context requires that the class have been managed by Android and started by Android.  You should instead call start activity using the context object you supply to Starter.

Try this :

```java
 public class Starter  {

    Context context;

    public Starter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void OpenOkraWidget(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, OkraWebActivity.class);
        this.context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```